# React Card not rendering on Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create a React App which should have two screens:

In the First Screen, the user can enter some input as a string and upon submitting it, the string should be passed on to `Screen2`

In `Screen2`, the entered text should be split and displayed as individual letters on a react bootstrap card.

The code which I have written for `Screen1` is working perfectly and passing the string as intended to `Screen2`. However, the `Screen2` is not displaying anything.

Code for App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route exact path="/Screen1" element={<Screen1 />} />
          <Route path="/Screen2/:text" component={Screen2} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

This the code for Screen1.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Screen1() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('')

  const handleTextChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (text.trim() === '') {
      setErrorMsg('Please enter some text.')
      return
    }
    setText('')
  }

  return (
    <div className="info">
      <h2>Screen 1</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Enter text:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={text}
            onChange={handleTextChange}
          />
        </label>
        <Link to={`/Screen2/${text}`}>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Link>
        {errorMsg && <p className="error">{errorMsg}</p>}
      </form>
      <Link to="/">Go back to home</Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the code for Screen2.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'

function Screen2() {
  const { text } = useParams() // extract the text from the URL
  const letters = text.split('') // convert text to array of characters

  return (
    <div className="info">
      <h2>Screen 2</h2>
      <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
        <Card.Body>
          {letters.map((letter, index) => (
            <Card.Text key={index}>{letter}</Card.Text> // render each letter
          ))}
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Screen2
```

I tried making the card from [react-bootstrap-documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#title-text-and-links)

Upon, inspecting and checking the console in Screen2, I got this error message:

[image: Console Error]

> Matched leaf route at location "/Screen2/eavdsdvsfs" does not have an
> element or Component. This means it will render an `<Outlet />` with a
> null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

Comment: Please include all relevant code you are working with as part of a complete [mcve]. In this case it's the router and routes. We can't really address issues with code we can't see.

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry, I added the routes from "App.js"

Comment: @Miner Hi, I referred this and upon changing the "<Route path="/Screen2/:text" component={Screen2} />" to "<Route path="/Screen2/:text" element={Screen2} />", the "matched leaf" error is gone.

But in its place, I got a new error:

```bundle.js:11850 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.```

Comment: The `<Route path="/Screen2/:text" component={Screen2} />` route should be `<Route path="/Screen2/:text" element={<Screen2 />} />`.

Comment: @DrewReese It's working perfectly. Thank you so much. I am beginner in this field, and you truly saved me a lot of worry.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to also include that the duplicate provides a bit of explanation as well. Cheers.

Comment: From what I understand you are using react-router/react-router-dom v6.x. The issue appears to be from the prop `component` you are using while routing to Screen2.

Changing the prop to `element` and supplying an element like with other routes on App.js should solve the issue.

Suggested fix: `<Route path="/Screen2/:text" element={<Screen2 />} />`

React Router v5 takes `component` prop to load a component when the route matches. React Router v6 does not support the `component` prop. It uses the `element` prop to load the element when the route matches.

Hope this helps.